# Extjs custom vtype

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, extjs4

im trying validate a textfield with a custom vtype to filter white spaces, ex: "  ".
I defined my custom vtype in the app.js (im using mvc pattern).

```
    Ext.Loader.setConfig({
        enabled : true,
        paths: {
            Ext: 'vendor/ext41/src',
            My: 'app'
        } 
    });
    Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
        descartarBlanco:  function(value) {
            return /^\s+$/.test(value);
        }
    });

    Ext.application({
        name: 'CRUDManantiales',
        appFolder: 'app',
        controllers: ['Ui','Usuarios'],
        ....
    });
```

But, Firebug show this error:

> TypeError: vtypes[vtype] is not a function

I would think that the syntax is correct. But, i dont know where insert the code of Vtype.
any idea ?.
Thanks.

Comment: When and where exactly do you get this error?

Comment: If you type in the console `Ext.form.field.VTypes` (after your app loads), is there your `descartarBlanco` entry?

Comment: Ext.form.field.VTypes shows the basics VTypes, but not show my custom VType "descartarBlanco"

Comment: Now that's mysterious. Do you actually define a vtype in your `app.js` file as posted above or you have it in another file?

Comment: Both. First i try as posted above. How not work, wrote the code in a external js "validator.js" and include this before "app.js"- But the problem was the same !

Answer (score 2):

I put my custom vtypes in my app's controller on before render form.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    ...
    init: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.control({
            ...
            'form': {
                beforerender: this.applyVtypes
            },
            ...
        })
   },
   ...
   applyVtypes: function() {
       Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
           descartarBlanco:  function(value) {
               return /^\s+$/.test(value);
           }
       }
   }
   ...    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I reached this question trying to find a solution as I faced the same issue. It worked fine when I added it to 'init:' in Ext.application.

```
    Ext.application({
            ..., 

            launch: function() { 
                ... 
            }, 

            init: function() {
                Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
                    descartarBlanco:  function(value) {
                        return /^\s+$/.test(value);
                    }
                }
                console.log(Ext.form.field.VTypes); // for verification
            }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your own email validation.

> xtype:'textfield',
>  fieldLabel: 'Email',
>  name: 'email',
>   maskRe: **/[a-z0-9_.-@+]/i**,//You can change it acccording to your
>   requirement.

Comment: This code won't check the characters already present in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the same issue but with Ext.data.Types it only worked when the type name was uppercase. When lowercase would get a similar message as to what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You use `Ext.Loader` so `Ext.form.field.VTypes` can be overwritten somewhere later. Try to add your vtype definition just before you actually use it.

Comment: mmm im use mvc pattern, i put te VType code into the app.js with the idea of that use the custom validator in all forms. so, where sugest overwritten the code ?.