# Is it possible to use regex field in cq:Widget (textarea)?

Tags: aem

I input valid RegExp in property editor, but it doesn't work.
Property name is `regex`, it is definitely present in 5.3 and 5.6 (and I have 5.5).

I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object /^/content/trainingSite/(.*)$/ has no method 'test'` and from javascript debugger I see, that `this.regex` is a string. Of course, string has no `test` method.

Since there's no RegExp type in property editor and CQ just dumps value for widget as string, it won't work at all this way. Am I missing something?

Comment: I suggest to add the tag [extjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extjs), since this is not CQ specific.

Comment: No, the problem is specific to CQ. In "plain" Ext I could just write regex literal in config and there would be no such problem as I met.

Comment: In ExtJS only the TextField supports `regex`. Your question seems broader ;-)

Comment: ok, I meant textfield only. They all have common widgt config format anyway.

Comment: @kirilloid how did you solve this problem? I knew it's quite old question, but I am experiencing the same issue, the CQ widget api shows the pathfield inherited from textbox, so the regex should be available as well to pathfield

Comment: I solved it with `vtype` (approved the answer). Actually, at some point later I stumbled upon correct syntax (or it was about functions...), but I don't have CQ instance at hand to check and can't google the right syntax now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of the ExtJS form fields, only the [TextField](http://dev.day.com/content/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.form.TextField) has a `regex` and `regexText` property.

The generic validation framework for ExtJS form fields are [**vtypes** (= validation types)](http://dev.day.com/content/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.form.VTypes):

```
var config = {
    xtype: "textfield",
    fieldLabel: "Path:",
    vtype: "my_path_structure"
}
```

And the vtypes need to be registered on `CQ.Ext.form.VTypes`:

```
CQ.Ext.form.VTypes["my_path_structure"] = /^/content/trainingSite/(.*)$/;
CQ.Ext.form.VTypes["my_path_structureText"] = "Invalid path";
```

- The first entry (`<name>`) can be a function or a javascript regexp.
- The `<name>Text` entry will be shown when validation failed.
- There is also `<name>Mask` which allows you to provide an optional mask which is validated in real-time while the user is entering something into the field.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417268/extjs-custom-vtype).

Comment: Nice workaround, it's better than creating whole new component.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, just feeding the value would throw a console error saying .test is not valid. My issue was resolved when I fed the regex value in this syntax :

```
regex="new RegExp(&quot;/content/dam/(.*)/(.*)&quot;)"
```

from eclipse and imported or like below in crxde-lite:

```
Name:regex Type:String Value:new RegExp("/content/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all we can use `String.prototype.match` with a string param. Also at least in AEM6 we can write regular expression as a string literal with slashes at both ends: `"/^\\/content\\/trainingSite\\/(.*)$/"` and it will work properly.